# Refactor array of objects with nested arrays using map do

Tags: ruby

I'm using the following code to try to remap the "usageByMonth" array that lives inside an array of multiple objects.

```
categorisedFeatures = response[:categorisedFeatures].map do |feature|
   newHistorical = (feature.dig(1, :historical)).map do |historical|
     usageByMonthRefactor = historical.dig(:usageByMonth)&.map { |(k, v)| { 'month': k, 'value': v } }
           newEntry = historical.merge({
               usageByMonth: usageByMonthRefactor
            })
     end
    newFeature = feature.dig(1).merge ({
      historical: newHistorical
    }) 
 feature&.map { |(k,v)| k=k , v=newFeature}

 end
```

The problem is that the output is repeating the same "historical" object multiple times and I'm not sure why.

Here is the output example for one of the "feature" elements:

CMS
{:historical=>[{:internalName=>"TOTAL_BLOG_POSTS_LIVE_EOM", :definition=>"Blogs live", :toolTip=>"Number of blogs with a "published" status at the end of the report month.", :tags=>[], :type=>"NUMBER", :name=>"Blogs", :usageByMonth=>[{:month=>:SEP, :value=>"741"}, {:month=>:OCT, :value=>"741"}, {:month=>:AUG, :value=>"741"}]}, {:internalName=>"BLOG_POST_VIEWS", :definition=>"Page views", :toolTip=>:null, :tags=>[], :type=>"NUMBER", :name=>"Blogs", :usageByMonth=>[{:month=>:SEP, :value=>"6651"}, {:month=>:OCT, :value=>"6601"}, {:month=>:AUG, :value=>"6957"}]}, {:internalName=>"LANDING_PAGE_VIEWS", :definition=>"Page views", :toolTip=>:null, :tags=>[], :type=>"NUMBER", :name=>"Landing Pages", :usageByMonth=>[{:month=>:SEP, :value=>"68"}, {:month=>:OCT, :value=>"163"}, {:month=>:AUG, :value=>"116"}]}, {:internalName=>"WEBSITE_PAGE_VIEWS", :definition=>"Page views", :toolTip=>:null, :tags=>[], :type=>"NUMBER", :name=>"Website Pages", :usageByMonth=>[{:month=>:SEP, :value=>"1041"}, {:month=>:OCT, :value=>"979"}, {:month=>:AUG, :value=>"1268"}]}], :realtime=>[]}
{:historical=>[{:internalName=>"TOTAL_BLOG_POSTS_LIVE_EOM", :definition=>"Blogs live", :toolTip=>"Number of blogs with a "published" status at the end of the report month.", :tags=>[], :type=>"NUMBER", :name=>"Blogs", :usageByMonth=>{:SEP=>"741", :OCT=>"741", :AUG=>"741"}}, {:internalName=>"BLOG_POST_VIEWS", :definition=>"Page views", :toolTip=>:null, :tags=>[], :type=>"NUMBER", :name=>"Blogs", :usageByMonth=>{:SEP=>"6651", :OCT=>"6601", :AUG=>"6957"}}, {:internalName=>"LANDING_PAGE_VIEWS", :definition=>"Page views", :toolTip=>:null, :tags=>[], :type=>"NUMBER", :name=>"Landing Pages", :usageByMonth=>{:SEP=>"68", :OCT=>"163", :AUG=>"116"}}, {:internalName=>"WEBSITE_PAGE_VIEWS", :definition=>"Page views", :toolTip=>:null, :tags=>[], :type=>"NUMBER", :name=>"Website Pages", :usageByMonth=>{:SEP=>"1041", :OCT=>"979", :AUG=>"1268"}}], :realtime=>[]}
{:historical=>[{:internalName=>"TOTAL_BLOG_POSTS_LIVE_EOM", :definition=>"Blogs live", :toolTip=>"Number of blogs with a "published" status at the end of the report month.", :tags=>[], :type=>"NUMBER", :name=>"Blogs", :usageByMonth=>[{:month=>:SEP, :value=>"741"}, {:month=>:OCT, :value=>"741"}, {:month=>:AUG, :value=>"741"}]}, {:internalName=>"BLOG_POST_VIEWS", :definition=>"Page views", :toolTip=>:null, :tags=>[], :type=>"NUMBER", :name=>"Blogs", :usageByMonth=>[{:month=>:SEP, :value=>"6651"}, {:month=>:OCT, :value=>"6601"}, {:month=>:AUG, :value=>"6957"}]}, {:internalName=>"LANDING_PAGE_VIEWS", :definition=>"Page views", :toolTip=>:null, :tags=>[], :type=>"NUMBER", :name=>"Landing Pages", :usageByMonth=>[{:month=>:SEP, :value=>"68"}, {:month=>:OCT, :value=>"163"}, {:month=>:AUG, :value=>"116"}]}, {:internalName=>"WEBSITE_PAGE_VIEWS", :definition=>"Page views", :toolTip=>:null, :tags=>[], :type=>"NUMBER", :name=>"Website Pages", :usageByMonth=>[{:month=>:SEP, :value=>"1041"}, {:month=>:OCT, :value=>"979"}, {:month=>:AUG, :value=>"1268"}]}], :realtime=>[]}

Here is my original input:

```
response = {
  "months": [
    "AUG",
    "SEP",
    "OCT"
  ],
  "categorisedTiers": {
    "CMS": "FREE",
    "MARKETING": "FREE",
    "OPERATIONS": "FREE",
    "SALES": "FREE",
    "SERVICE": "FREE"
  },
  "categorisedFeatures": {
    "PLATFORM": {
      "historical": [
        {
          "internalName": "TOTAL_CONTACTS_CREATED_IN_MONTH",
          "definition": "New contacts",
          "toolTip": "Number of contacts that were created in the report month.",
          "tags": [],
          "type": "NUMBER",
          "name": "Contacts",
          "usageByMonth": {
            "SEP": "33",
            "OCT": "35",
            "AUG": "40"
          }
        },
        {
          "internalName": "TOTAL_CONTACTS_QUALIFIED_IN_MONTH",
          "definition": "MQLs",
          "toolTip": "Number of contacts that were set with internal value 'marketingqualifiedlead' in the 'lifecycle stage' property in the report month.",
          "tags": [],
          "type": "NUMBER",
          "name": "Contacts",
          "usageByMonth": {
            "SEP": "0",
            "OCT": "0",
            "AUG": "0"
          }
        },
        {
          "internalName": "TOTAL_CONTACTS_BECAME_CUSTOMERS_IN_MONTH",
          "definition": "Customers",
          "toolTip": "Number of contacts that were set with internal value 'customer' in the 'lifecycle stage' property in the report month.",
          "tags": [],
          "type": "NUMBER",
          "name": "Contacts",
          "usageByMonth": {
            "SEP": "0",
            "OCT": "0",
            "AUG": "0"
          }
        },
        {
          "internalName": "CONTACTS_SCORED",
          "definition": "Contacts scored",
          "toolTip": "Overall percentage of all contacts with the 'HubSpot score' not equal to 0, in the report month.",
          "tags": [
            "PRO+"
          ],
          "type": "PERCENTAGE",
          "name": "Contacts",
          "usageByMonth": {
            "SEP": "25.09",
            "OCT": "25.05",
            "AUG": "25.11"
          }
        },
        {
          "internalName": "PERCENTAGE_CONTACTS_ASSIGNED",
          "definition": "Contacts assigned",
          "toolTip": "Overall percentage of contacts with an owner.",
          "tags": [],
          "type": "PERCENTAGE",
          "name": "Contacts",
          "usageByMonth": {
            "SEP": "19.67",
            "OCT": "19.65",
            "AUG": "19.67"
          }
        },
        {
          "internalName": "TOTAL_CONTACTS_CONTACTED_IN_MONTH",
          "definition": "Contacts contacted",
          "toolTip": "Number of contacts that were contacted through a call, chat conversation, LinkedIn message, postal mail, meeting, sales email, SMS, or WhatsApp message in the report month.",
          "tags": [],
          "type": "NUMBER",
          "name": "Contacts",
          "usageByMonth": {
            "SEP": "3",
            "OCT": "3",
            "AUG": "5"
          }
        },
        {
          "internalName": "TOTAL_CONVERSATIONS_STARTED_IN_MONTH",
          "definition": "Conversations started",
          "toolTip": "Number of conversations started, via any channel, in the report month (e.g. emails, chats, FaceBook Messanger, etc.)",
          "tags": [],
          "type": "NUMBER",
          "name": "Conversations",
          "usageByMonth": {
            "SEP": "0",
            "OCT": "0",
            "AUG": "0"
          }
        },
        {
          "internalName": "TOTAL_CUSTOM_REPORTS",
          "definition": "Custom reports",
          "toolTip": "Total number of custom reports as of the end of the report month.",
          "tags": [],
          "type": "NUMBER",
          "name": "Reporting",
          "usageByMonth": {
            "AUG": "27",
            "SEP": "27",
            "OCT": "27"
          }
        },
        {
          "internalName": "TOTAL_DASHBOARDS",
          "definition": "Dashboards",
          "toolTip": "Total number of dashboards as of the end of the report month.",
          "tags": [],
          "type": "NUMBER",
          "name": "Reporting",
          "usageByMonth": {
            "AUG": "4",
            "SEP": "4",
            "OCT": "4"
          }
        },
        {
          "internalName": "TOTAL_TEMPLATE_EMAIL_SENDS_THIS_MONTH",
          "definition": "Templates sent",
          "toolTip": :null,
          "tags": [],
          "type": "NUMBER",
          "name": "Templates",
          "usageByMonth": {
            "SEP": "0",
            "OCT": "0",
            "AUG": "0"
          }
        },
        {
          "internalName": "TOTAL_PAGE_VIEWS",
          "definition": "Page views",
          "toolTip": "Number of page views recorded in the report month. A page view is counted every time the HubSpot tracking code is loaded on a browser.",
          "tags": [],
          "type": "NUMBER",
          "name": "Traffic Analytics",
          "usageByMonth": {
            "SEP": "13522",
            "OCT": "12599",
            "AUG": "18599"
          }
        },
        {
          "internalName": "TOTAL_WORKFLOWS_CREATED_IN_MONTH",
          "definition": "Workflows created",
          "toolTip": :null,
          "tags": [
            "PRO+"
          ],
          "type": "NUMBER",
          "name": "Workflows",
          "usageByMonth": {
            "SEP": "0",
            "OCT": "1",
            "AUG": "0"
          }
        }
      ],
      "realtime": [
        {
          "internalName": "TOTAL_CUSTOM_OBJECTS",
          "definition": "Active custom objects",
          "toolTip": "Total number of active custom objects. This data is real time.",
          "tags": [
            "ENTERPRISE"
          ],
          "type": "NUMBER",
          "name": "Custom Objects",
          "realtimeValue": "0"
        }
      ]
    },
    "OPERATIONS": {
      "historical": [
        {
          "internalName": "DUPLICATE_RECORDS",
          "definition": "Duplicate records",
          "toolTip": "Count of duplicate records at end of report month.",
          "tags": [
            "PRO+"
          ],
          "type": "NUMBER",
          "name": "Data Quality",
          "usageByMonth": {
            "AUG": "0",
            "SEP": "0",
            "OCT": "0"
          }
        },
        {
          "internalName": "TOTAL_PROGRAMMABLE_ACTION_EVENTS",
          "definition": "Programmable actions",
          "toolTip": :null,
          "tags": [
            "PRO+"
          ],
          "type": "NUMBER",
          "name": "Workflows",
          "usageByMonth": {
            "SEP": "0",
            "OCT": "0",
            "AUG": "0"
          }
        }
      ],
      "realtime": [
        {
          "internalName": "DATASETS_CREATED",
          "definition": "Datasets live",
          "toolTip": "Number of datasets at the end of the report month. This data is real time.",
          "tags": [
            "ENTERPRISE"
          ],
          "type": "NUMBER",
          "name": "Dataset",
          "realtimeValue": "0"
        }
      ]
    },
    "CMS": {
      "historical": [
        {
          "internalName": "TOTAL_BLOG_POSTS_LIVE_EOM",
          "definition": "Blogs live",
          "toolTip": "Number of blogs with a \"published\" status at the end of the report month.",
          "tags": [],
          "type": "NUMBER",
          "name": "Blogs",
          "usageByMonth": {
            "SEP": "741",
            "OCT": "741",
            "AUG": "741"
          }
        },
        {
          "internalName": "BLOG_POST_VIEWS",
          "definition": "Page views",
          "toolTip": :null,
          "tags": [],
          "type": "NUMBER",
          "name": "Blogs",
          "usageByMonth": {
            "SEP": "6651",
            "OCT": "6601",
            "AUG": "6957"
          }
        },
        {
          "internalName": "LANDING_PAGE_VIEWS",
          "definition": "Page views",
          "toolTip": :null,
          "tags": [],
          "type": "NUMBER",
          "name": "Landing Pages",
          "usageByMonth": {
            "SEP": "68",
            "OCT": "163",
            "AUG": "116"
          }
        },
        {
          "internalName": "WEBSITE_PAGE_VIEWS",
          "definition": "Page views",
          "toolTip": :null,
          "tags": [],
          "type": "NUMBER",
          "name": "Website Pages",
          "usageByMonth": {
            "SEP": "1041",
            "OCT": "979",
            "AUG": "1268"
          }
        }
      ],
      "realtime": []
    }
    
  }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated!

I've tried just re-declaring "newFeature" at the end instead of the last "map" argument. However, when this happens while the repeated "historical" objects are gone, I don't get the "key" value for example, for the first object the key is "PLATFORM".

Comment: "Refactor" and "remap" need to be defined. To do that you need to show the desired result as well as what you are getting. To do that you need to take a machete to `response` to make it much smaller, reduced to its essentials. Note `....map do |feature|; newHistorical = (feature.dig(1, :historical)).map...` is very unusual. One would normal see it written, `....map do |_key, value|;
newHistorical = (value.dig(:historical)).map...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line of the code is the cause of the dublication:

```
feature&.map { |(k,v)| k=k , v=newFeature}
```

Because feature has 2 elements.There is a simple example:

```
[0,1]&.map { |(k,v)| k=2 , v=3} =>>>> [[2, 3], [2, 3]]
```

In this case, if we put feature in an array and add flatten at the end will fix the issue:

```
[feature]&.map { |(k,v)| k=k , v=newFeature}.flatten
```